# How to initialize a std::array<char, N> with a string literal omitting the trailing '\0'

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have a file structure where fixed length strings have no trailing zero.
How to initialize fields as std::array without trailing zero:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Data {
    // Compiles, but it has an undesired '\0':
    std::array<char, 6> undesired_number{"12345"};
    // Does not compile:
    std::array<char, 5> number{"12345"}; // stripping '\0'
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: What's the compiler error? Incompatible types? I'm afraid it's simply not possible based on a character string literal.

Comment: Why do you have to use a string literal to initialize it?

Comment: @Barmar just for convenience

Comment: If it's just about reading from a file, you won't need the literal. If it's about writing to a file, you should only omit the trailing \0 once you actually do the writing, not when you're initializing the data.

Comment: @JSQuareD I would like to have the data definition the same (for reading and writing, and yes I push it into a stream via a raw write)

Comment: Since string literals are always appended with `'\0'` or equivalents my bet is on some intermediate `constexpr`/template magic which would take the literal and cut out the zero and returned a truncated value. However it might be problematic, since you cannot modify string literals. Maybe exception for constant expressions allow it.

Comment: You could make a user-defined literal

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Making a helper function

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::array<char, N - 1>
to_array(const char (&a)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {{a[Is]...}};
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<char, N - 1> to_array(const char (&a)[N])
{
    return to_array(a, std::make_index_sequence<N - 1>());
}
```

And then

```
struct Data {
    std::array<char, 5> number{to_array("12345")}; // stripping '\0'
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/S8cJdH)

Comment: I wonder if this will compile into one copy of the literal, or two, one with terminator and one without.

Comment: @luk32, depends on compiler and optimization settings. For instance, g++ with O3 does not have a literal there at all.

Comment: Works nicely with C++11 after getting a `make_index_sequence` and changing to `std::array<char, 5> number = to_array("12345"); `

Comment: You can add `constexpr` before the return type to enable compile initialization of the `std::array`. I checked the assembly output of g++, and adding this allowed `static const` variables to be initialized as part of the executable image. Without `constexpr` it did run-time initialization.

Comment: @DanielStevens: Added.

Comment: Why the double curly braces?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: `std::array` is mostly `struct { T data[N]; };`, so with aggregate initialization, first bracket is for the class `array`, second one is for its `data` member. (one pair can be omitted but compiler might warn about the "missing" braces).

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks! I find it odd that `std::array` has no constructor from `initializer_list` which would help avoid the extra braces.

Comment: Great answer! Is this solution still applicable to C++17? It seems that a straightforward for-loop would suffice as long as the function is marked `constexpr`, right?

Comment: @303: With default initializable type, such as `char`, you can indeed use for-range (even since C++14 (where for-range is allowed in `constexpr` function, and `std::array`'s methods are marked `constexpr`)). You cannot **initialize** with for-range, just assign/copy, which is fine for `char`.

Comment: I see what you mean now, the for-loop method only works when a `std::array` of `char` is required, it wouldn't work with a type of `const char`. For the more generic use case, where one simply needs to initialize a `std::array` of type `const char` with a string literal, a deduction guide could be used instead. (To obtain a `std::array` of `const char`s instead of a `std::array` of a single `const char*`.)

Answer (score 1):

A string literal **is** NUL-terminated, in C++ (unlike  C) you cannot take it off by providing a `Length - 1` size; therefore it cannot be done *directly*, also considering that `array` internally is a `T[N]`.

Comment: The standard doesn't require that `array` internally be a `T[N]`. Some think it should, for the cases `N > 0` anyway