# Can I initialize a std::array<uint8_t with a string literal?

Tags: c++, embedded

I write a lot of C code interacting with instruments using UART serial ports.  I'm starting a new project where I'm trying to use a more object oriented approach with C++.  Here's how I've defined and sent commands in the past using C.

```
uint8_t  pubx04Cmd[] = "$PUBX,04*37\r\n";
HAL_UART_Transmit(&hUART1, pubx04Cmd, sizeof(pubx04Cmd), 5000);
```

Which is pretty darn simple. C++ `std::array`s have the size built in which seems kind of useful. But here's the only way I've figured out how to do it.

```
const char pubx04CString[] = "$PUBX,04*37\r\n";
std::array<uint8_t, 14> pubx04CPPArray;
std::copy(std::begin(pubx04CString), std::end(pubx04CString), pubx04CPPArray.begin());
HAL_UART_Transmit(&hUART1, pubx04CPPArray.data(), pubx04CPPArray.size(), 5000);
```

Which seems pretty clunky compared to the C way to do it.

- Is there a cleaner way to do this using `std::array`?
- Is there any real benefit to using `std::array`s vs C arrays for this situation?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484233/how-to-initialize-a-stdarraychar-n-with-a-string-literal-omitting-the-trail

Comment: So, I guess you want to avoid the explicit `std::copy()` call in preference to use a correct cast right?

Comment: `std::array<uint8_t, 14> pubx04Cmd{"$PUBX,04*37\r\n"};`

Comment: @273K write an elaborated answer please.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I looked at that post earlier but that's even more complicated than what I'm doing now.

Comment: @273K That works! If there is a way to do it without having to count characters, that would be even better.  But that is probably asking too much.  I tried something like that earlier but made it too complicated and got compiler errors.

Comment: And thanks to everyone for the instantaneous help.

Comment: To do it without having to count characters, you have to apply size deducing, this is possible only with help of function templates and `auto`, see the link in the first comment. This function is already available in C++20 ([`std::to_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array)). You may copy a possible implementation to an earlier C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::array` is an aggregate, i.e. a possible implementation may be like

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
struct array {
  T a[S];
  // ...
};
```

The enclosed array can be initializes as usual:

```
std::array<uint8_t, 14> pubx04Cmd{"$PUBX,04*37\r\n"};
```

Comment: It is an aggregate, but is the array member required to be the first member or is that implementation-dependent?

Comment: @Ben It is required. *This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member.* See [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: @273K First - thanks for the help.  I have one more question.  Can Ido something like this: std::array<const uint8_t, 14> pubx04CPPArray = {"$PUBX,04*37\r\n"}; But HAL_UART_Transmit(&hUART1, pubx04CPPArray.data(), pubx04CPPArray.size(), 5000) gives an error since it is expecting a pointer to pubx04CPPArray.data().  I'm guessing the way I added const to pubx04CPPArray means it became a const pointer which is why I'm getting the error.  This isn't a big deal but making things const where possible seems like good practice for embedded systems.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: `const std::array<uint8_t, 14> pubx04CPPArray = {"$PUBX,04*37\r\n"};` is better for reading then `std::array<const uint8_t, 14> pubx04CPPArray`. Using `const` as much as possible is a good habit. IMHO HAL_UART API is not well designed.

Comment: @273K - I'm really grateful for your help and I completely agree with your comment about the HAL_UART API.  In fact, the entire STM32HAL is really frustrating to use.  Just to finish this off, here's the least clunky way I've figured out how to do this.   
const char pubx04CString[] = "$PUBX,04*37\r\n";
std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(pubx04CString) - 1> pubx04CPPArray2 = { };
std::copy(std::begin(pubx04CString), std::end(pubx04CString)-1, pubx04CPPArray2.begin());